# MVC ajax POST info about ApplicationUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have an entity that consists of ApllicationUser as a  foreign Key:

```
public class Trades
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public double Price { get; set; }
   public double Volume { get; set; }
   public string InstrumentName { get; set; }
   public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Then i try to post a trade using AJAX.

```
var tradeData = {
    "Price": 1,
    "Volume": 1,
    "InstrumentName": "instrumentName",
    "User": "@User.Identity.Name"
};
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/TradesAPI/",
    method: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(tradeData),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function () {
        alert('executed!');
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert("Transacion has not been executed");
    }
});
```

Unfortunetely ApplicationUser is not being serialised to ApplicationUSer as it is posted a string. What have I done wrong? Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Try just with `data: tradeData,`

Comment: Can you check the console for errors ?

Comment: Is this supposed to work in anyway? Are you following a tutorial or something? Because I can't see a case where `"@User.Identity.Name"` would be correctly translated into an `ApplicationUser`. You should try transforming your `User` property into a string and then, on server-side, resolving the name into an `ApplicationUser`

Comment: @Hackerman i tried it and received error Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: entity

Comment: @mybirthname there is no error. User is saved with null value

Comment: @Atlasmaybe I am not following any tutorial just trying to find a way how to save ApllicationUser that is a foerign key in a table

Comment: It seems that this has a `null` value, `@User.Identity.Name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have a class "A" that contains a reference to "B" and this "B" has also a reference to "A" (even if not direct), the proccess of  serialization doesn't work. It's like an "infinite loop". 
I suggest you change the `ApplicationUser`(type of `User`)  to `string` and use it to get the model (on code-behind), if you need it.

If you need to get the user from within the controller, use the `User` property of `Controller`. 
If you need it from the view, would populate what you specifically need in the `ViewData`, or you could just call `User`.

Ex. `@User.Identity.Name`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Indrit Kello. I changed my model so I have

```
public class Trades
{
 public int ID { get; set; }
 public double Price { get; set; }
 public double Volume { get; set; }
 public string InstrumentName { get; set; }
 public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

I decided to take info about user on server in API controller insted of taking data about User in a View.

```
    public void CreateTradeAPI(Trades trade)
    {
        trade.UserID =User.Identity.Name;
        _context.UsersTrades.Add(trade);
        _context.SaveChanges();
   }
```

And I have what i wanted :)